# Bootstrap 2 column design with a togglable side bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started using Bootstrap and I am struggling with making a design that contains 2 columns, each 50% of the available width of the screen. I can do this, but I also want to add a sidebar(eventually 2) that can toggle via a button on the top nav bar of the website. As of now I have my two columns and my sidebar, but a problem arises when the sidebar is showing. I have been playing with it and the two divs only appear if the sidebar is hidden.  I want the two divs, map and text-container, to take up all of the width of the screen. So once the sidebar is showing the two divs would shrink and move to the right.

The current way the website site is laid out, involves a div that contains my two columns. I don't know if I am heading in the correct direction or not.

I am unsure if it has to do with CSS or JS, but here is my CSS for my div main div, screen-content, and the two columns it contains, map & text-container.

```
 html, body, #container {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
 body {
   padding-top: 50px;
  }
 input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 0;
  }
 #sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
     transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }
 #content-screen{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 97.5%;
  }
 #map {
   width: 50%;
   height: 100%;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   float: left;
  }
 #text-container{
   width: 50%;
   height: 100%;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   border-style: solid;
   float: left;
  }
```

Here is my [Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yarxxhe6/) that contains most of my code.

Thank you very much homeslices!

Comment: Something like this work for you? http://www.bootply.com/6pIepHrSce (Click readings to toggle the visibility of the left-column)

Comment: Yes that will work pretty well.